# Alternate UI Pattern for slider

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, guidelines, sliders

I am designing tablet form where i have to capture term of investment for a deposit. Currently, i have designed a typical slider component but we have some technical limitation due to which we are not able to implement it. So, i have designed segmented buttons having most common terms and with an option to select custom term. If tapped on custom, a free text will be shown where a customer can input any value.

So, i want to validate my pattern with the community whether this pattern will work or not or Can anyone suggest me any other alternative pattern for this?
[image]

Comment: Have you considered the good old [spinbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb246411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? You could place the most common values on it, and provide a "custom" button beside it to allow for other values..

Comment: The problem with this, the common values will be hidden within the spinner. Unless the user clicks the values won't be revealed. But this is good idea though.

Answer (score 2):

If your users are financial professional or so it could be convient to use month as a unit of time.

But if your users are not specific it is not convient to measure long time periods in months. It is strange to hear "I am 120 months old", right? This way pushes people to calculate in mind or paper to more convient units. *Don't make me think*, the famous principle is broken here.

So a control with scale 1 to 60 monthes could be mentally hard to perceive. It's not important implementation: either you use slider or set of 60 radiobuttons.

Maybe you could re-think it on more conceptual level, considering your users:

[image]

Another way to make month scale more easilly is to choose time chunks:
[image]

Comment: The users who will use this component will be mid aged/elderly people looking to open a term deposit. Their task is to choose a investment term from a scale of 1-60 months. Depending on the term they choose interest rates for monthly, quarterly, halfyearly, yearly will be shown from which can customer can select interest that is yielding highest return. Your first approach might not work for the reason that i have to show interest projections for monthly, quarterly, half yearly, yearly. Designed your last approach by having the common terms upfront also with an option to input a customer term.

Comment: So in this case shouldn't the monthly, quarterly, half yearly, yearly division be better? So shift users' choice from terms to  benefit, which is more valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a stepper (-/+) interface like the one in the image below. These are *very* popular because they're used in **gaming** all the time. I have used them in tablet apps with great success.

Make sure to change the number field to fit your needs, in the example below it's difficult to say if 3 or 6 is a lot of skill or not unless you're familiar with this game. In the same way, make sure you mention you can invest for up to 60 months.

Finally, **test this idea with users** who might typically use the app; even some relatives who invest a few thousands in stock will give you a rough idea. These buttons have worked really great for my users but maybe your users need a different thing.

[image: gaming skills]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a slider then the 'radio + custom' seems like a good approach.

It looks like you have a maximum value of 60 months so I would put some kind of feedback that indicates this. Perhaps a colored bar or something akin to a thermometer (in style) that shows the levels and how close they are to the max.